# WSO2 disabling port redirect from 9763 to 9443

Tags: nginx, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have a single instance deployment of WSO2 and now I want to be able to access the carbon management services like publisher/store etc through http. I have tried the following configurations in *catalina-server.xml*. I also want to use nginx as reverse proxy through http port for carbon consoles. Please help. I have also tried editing the *axis2.xml* to add port mappings for nginx 80 and 443 port. Currently when i run carbon console through 9763 it gets redirected to 9443 and after adding mappings in *axis2.xml* it responds as requested url not found for /publisher/..../login.jag

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Service className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService" name="Catalina">
    <!--
    optional attributes:
    proxyPort="80"
    -->
    <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               port="9763"
               bindOnInit="false"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               acceptorThreadCount="2"
               maxThreads="250"
               minSpareThreads="50"
               disableUploadTimeout="false"
               connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
               maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
               acceptCount="200"
               server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
               compression="on"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!--
    optional attributes:
    proxyPort="443"
    Added sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" for poodle vulnerability fix
    -->
    <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               port="9443"
               bindOnInit="false"
               sslProtocol="TLS"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               acceptorThreadCount="2"
               maxThreads="250"
               minSpareThreads="50"
               disableUploadTimeout="false"
               enableLookups="false"
               connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
               maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
               acceptCount="200"
               server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
               clientAuth="false"
               compression="on"
               scheme="https"
               secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="true"
               compressionMinSize="2048"
               noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
               keystoreFile="${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
               keystorePass="wso2carbon"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <!--Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" pathname="${carbon.home}/repository/conf/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml"/-->
        <Realm className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.realms.CarbonTomcatRealm"/>
        <Host name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" deployOnStartup="false" autoDeploy="false"
              appBase="${carbon.home}/repository/deployment/server/webapps/">
            <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve"/>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
                   prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log"
                   pattern="combined"/>
            <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="600"/>
            <Valve className="org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve"/>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the following line in `carbon.xml`.

```
<EnableHTTPAdminConsole>true</EnableHTTPAdminConsole>
```

Please note this is not recommended in production environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although now I have configured nginx proxy and its working like a charm.

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa Please accept the correct answer. it will help others who face same issue.